# Telegram Bot Bad Gateway

Tags: php, guzzle, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to upload picture using Telegram Bot API using the following code

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])){
        $new = fopen($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], "rb");
        $contents = fread($new, $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']);
        fclose($new);
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post("https://api.telegram.org/botMyApiKey/sendPhoto", [
            'body'    => ['chat_id' => '11111111', 'photo' => $contents]
        ]);
        var_dump($response);
}else{
        echo("No File");
}
```

I am getting **`Nginx 502 Bad Gateway`**. Am I using the correct method? I have no issues in obtaining `getMe` using the API. 
P.S I am using Guzzle 5.3.0 for php compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it as a multipart post.

```
$client->post(
    'https://api.telegram.org/botMyApiKey/sendPhoto', 
    array(
        'multipart' => array(
            array(
                'name'     => 'chat_id',
                'contents' => '1111111'
            ),
            array(
                'name'     => 'photo',
                'contents' => $contents
            )
        )
    )
);
```

[Guzzle documentation reference](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-files)

**For Guzzle 5.3**

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client(['defaults' => [
    'verify' => false
]]);

$response = $client->post('https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/sendPhoto', [
    'body' => [
        'chat_id' => 'xxxxx',
        'photo' => fopen(__DIR__ . '/test.jpg', 'r')
    ]
]);

var_dump($response);
```

Note: you must pass the file handle to the 'photo' attribute and not the contents of the file.

Comment: I am using Guzzle 5.3 . Multipart option is available only in latest version. I am using old guzzle version for php compatibility.

Comment: http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/request.html See section "POST requests". The Telegram API requires you to upload photo's in multipart/form-data

Comment: See me edit, you must pass the file handle and not the file contents.

Comment: I tried passing file handle and it resulted in ***[status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request***. I have no idea why.

Comment: I updated my answer with the full code snippet I used. This works perfectly for me. I did however get the 502 error when I passed the file contents.

Comment: Please checkout my posted solution.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. Pasting my solution for others.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], __DIR__."/temp/".$_FILES['photo']['name']); //Important for Form Upload
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->createRequest('POST', 'https://api.telegram.org/botMyApiKey/sendPhoto');
$postBody = $request->getBody();
$postBody->setField('chat_id', '11111111');
$postBody->addFile(new PostFile('photo', fopen(__DIR__."/temp/".$_FILES['photo']['name'], "r") ));
try{
     $response = $client->send($request);
     var_dump($response);
}catch(\Exception $e){
     echo('<br><strong>'.$e->getMessage().'</strong>');
}
```

I am puzzled as to why this works with this kind of Guzzle approach and not the other one. I suspect Guzzle not setting the correct header type with the first approach.